# Predicting process end time

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a simple problem that I'm having more trouble with than I should.

It's pretty straight forward: I have a time the process started `_startTime`, and the current time. I also have the total number of records I need to process `_records`, and the current record number `_current`.

How can I get a simple linear prediction of the end time? I've ended up in a rabbit hole of differencing ticks and stuff, but I imagine there's some simple DateTime or TimeSpan trickery I could be using,

```
TimeSpan delta = DateTime.Now - _startTime;
float progress = (float)_records / (float)_current;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm really sounds much simpler than it is probably

```
TimeSpan timeTakenSoFar = DateTime.Now - _startTime;
double percentageDoneSoFar = (double)_current / (double)_records;
TimeSpan timeTakingInTotal = timeTakenSoFar / percentageDoneSoFar;
DateTime finishTime = _startTime.Add(timeTakingInTotal);
```

This should work.

**Update:**

According to MSDN you cannot divide TimeSpan, but in that case you can use ticks: (I don't have a C# compiler at hand to check if it's 100% syntactically correct)

```
TimeSpan timeTakenSoFar = DateTime.Now - _startTime;
double percentageDoneSoFar = (double)_current / (double)_records;
double timeTakingInTotalInTicks = timeTakenSoFar.Ticks / percentageDoneSoFar;
DateTime finishTime = _startTime.AddTicks((long)timeTakingInTotal);
```

Comment: Maybe just clarify your answer, `percentageDoneSoFar = _records / _current;` is not really percentage... 800 / 400 = 2, not 50%

Comment: oh - sorry wrong - updated, thx for noticing, that's why descriptive variable names are so important :)

Comment: And you'll have to cast one of them to a `double`, probably. Also, `timeTakingInTotal` should probably be renamed to `timeRemaining` or something.

Comment: That's perfect (with the update), thanks! I knew I was just getting my head in a spin - that's the trouble with modifying code with a CEO tapping his feet waiting for results :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a sample every few cycles, and determine how long they took from start time.

```
now.subtract(_startTtime)
```

Divide that by the _current pointer, and get the time per cycle.

Multiple the time/cycle with (`(_records - _current)` <- cycles you have left to do)

The higher your "sample" resolution, the more accurate your result... but it is still just a prediction.

Answer (score 0):

```
var restRecords = _records - _current;
var averageTimeForRecord = delta.TotalMilliseconds / _current;
var restTime = restRecords * averageTimeForRecord;
var finishDate = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(restTime);
```

Maybe that is what you need?